Не могу подключится к базе данных YDB
Не могу подключиться к базе данных созданных в яндекс облаке YDB. Какую-то конкретную ошибку не выдаёт. Просто никак не может подключится. Читал руководство YDB по подключению, Chat GPT использовал, в интернете искал. Ничего не помогает. Использую Python, FAST API.
async def get_ydb_client():
endpoint = os.getenv("YDB_ENDPOINT")
database = os.getenv("YDB_DATABASE")
oauth_token = os.getenv("OAUTH_TOKEN")

if not endpoint:
    logger.error("Переменная окружения YDB_ENDPOINT не установлена или пуста.")
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="YDB_ENDPOINT не установлена")

if not database:
    logger.error("Переменная окружения YDB_DATABASE не установлена или пуста.")
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="YDB_DATABASE не установлена")

if not oauth_token:
    logger.error("Переменная окружения OAUTH_TOKEN не установлена или пуста.")
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="OAUTH_TOKEN не установлена")

# Используем синхронный AccessTokenCredentials с асинхронным драйвером
credentials = ydb.AccessTokenCredentials(oauth_token)
driver_config = ydb.aio.Driver(endpoint=endpoint, database=database, credentials=credentials)

driver = ydb.aio.Driver(driver_config)
# Ожидаем подключения асинхронно
if not await driver.wait(timeout=20):
    logger.error("Не удалось подключиться к YDB за отведенное время")
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Ошибка подключения к YDB")

logger.info("Подключение к YDB успешно установлено.")
return driver


"Не могу подключиться к базе данных созданных в яндекс облаке YDB. Какую-то конкретную ошибку не выдаёт" —

В том то и дело, что конкретную ошибку и не выдаёт, Мол то и то у тебя не правильно. Вот и не понятно. Просто не подключается: "Не удалось подключиться к YDB за отведенное время"

Вы же понимаете, что это как раз таки то, что нужно указать в вопросе? Поверьте, это многое меняет

Я не эксперт, но по тому, что вы сказали, я могу сделать 2 вывода: 1) Либо сайт не даёт подключиться к себе (может быть есть ограничивающая политика (у Яндекса это часто является причиной такого рода проблем) 2) Либо в вашем коде указано неверное подключение (или способ неверный). Без ошибки же ничего не было понятно, а так прогресс :)
